# InputConnection constantly inactive on EditTexts in a custom adapter

Tags: android, android-edittext, adapter

I have a custom adapter which I created using [this](http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-titles-icons-counter/) tutorial.

This worked so far, but now I wanted the button to switch out the TextView for an EditText once pressed.

That also works, whenever I tap on the button, it changes its icon and the text field appears.

**The Problem**

I can't focus the EditText. It drops focus right after the software keyboard appears.

Also I get this warning:

> IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection

It seems that whenever I tap on the text field, the item in the listview is redrawn as the button also reverts back to its original icon.

My theory:

Then the "old" text field doesn't exist anymore and it tells me it's inactive.

[image: My current listview]

Comment: Did u find a solution to this issue? Even I am facing a similar issue but could not find the right solution.

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell you exactly what went wrong. What I believe is, that somehow the list entry was reloaded when I focused it. No idea what happened there, but now I solved this problem simply basing my code on another tutorial. I can't tell you which tutorial that was, though :(.

I think it had something to do with ViewHolders. In my original version I didn't use them and in the reworked version, I do.

Here's what I've been using this code for, maybe you can make use of it: (MyAdapter.java, MyLocationsActivity.java & MyLocationsItem.java): https://github.com/CiriousJoker/HomingCompass/